# solution for nested forms

Tags: html, forms, nested-forms

is there a way to have a nested form?

like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text".... />
    <input type="text".... />
    <form action="some action">
        <input type="submit" .... />
    </form>
</form>
```

if not, how would I go around getting the same function without nested forms

Comment: What do you want to achieve with a nested form? As a note: With HTML5 form elements can also be outside a `<form>`-element and are coupled using the [`form`-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't have nested forms but there is a simple solution to your problem.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="action1" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="action2" />
</form>
```

If you use PHP this code will handle your form submissions:

```
//if user clicks on the first submit button, action1 is triggered
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'action1') {
    // do something    
}

//if user clicks on the second submit button, action2 is triggered    
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'action2') {
    // do something else
}
```

ps: As I see you work with C# and .NET, this would be translated into:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    ....

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string action)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) == "action1") {
            // Do something
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) == "action2") {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    ...
}
```